# Change sql parameter based on a public variable from an if statement

Tags: sql, vba, if-statement

I am currently working in vb.net windows form applications with an sql back end. I am currently having a problem with trying to lean out some code. I have a combobox that is databound to an sql query. I am trying to set up an event for selection change committed that will run an sql query and insert a string dependent upon the selected value of the combobox. I know of a way to do it that would force me to repeat the actual sql statement 6 times but I wanted to do it in a more short hand version. Here is my code:

```
  Dim MachineEnd as string
        'declare machine end string
    If Combobox.SelectedValue = 5 Then
        MachineEnd = "StringA"
    ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 6 Then
        MachineEnd = "StringB"
    ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 7 Then
        MachineEnd = "StringC"
    ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 8 Then
        MachineEnd = "StringD"
    ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 18 Then
        MachineEnd = "StringE"
    ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 15 Then
         MachineEnd = "StringF"
        End if

        'load quick view
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT " _
                                            & "RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M, ColA) AS varchar), 2) " _
                                            & "+ RIGHT ('0' + Cast(DATEPART(DD, ColA) AS varchar), 2) " _
                                            & "+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, ColA) AS varchar), 2) " _
                                            & "+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, ColA) AS varchar), 2) AS 'ColNumber', BuildOrder, TimeStamp " _
                                            & "from table1 Where Machine = @Machine AND @MachineFinish IS NULL " _
                                            & "AND Col1 IS NOT NULL", conn1)
            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Machine", CBMachine.SelectedValue)
            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachinEFinish", MachineEnd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
            sql.Fill(dt)
            Datagridview.DataSource = dt
        End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using
```

My problem comes in on the "MachineEnd" variable. Due to the end if statement not including the sql query I will leave the "MachineEnd" variable in the parameter statement undefined. However, if I move my end if statement to include the sql query I would have to copy the sql statement 6 times over and I want to try and do it in less lines. I think I need to either make the MachineEnd a public vatiable or use a different type of vb.net command, maybe a select case statement. The reason I am doing this is because I have different column names that match stringA, stringB, etc. etc. and I need to declare them as null when I load the datagridview.

--------------Post Edit-------------------------
Made changes to match dan's idea. I tried this and it looks like its working, however, I am getting an error that says the "machineEnd" variable is being used before it is assigned a value and could result in a dbnull. But, when I run the code and add a watch to the variable it says that the correct string is tied to the variable. But my datagridview is not populating correctly. I put my sql code into the sql server management studio and the code ran correctly. I am not sure what is going on with this.

-------------------Edit 2----------------------------------
I found out that using the addwithvalue parameter statement is causing the datagridview to come back blank. If I use a & MachineEnd & in my sql statement the code actually works. considering that the combobox is databound I am pretty sure an sql injection attack is fairly unlikely.

Comment: I haven't used vb in a while, but in most languages, if you instantiate a variable outside of the if statement, it will be the proper scope. Try adding `MachineEnd = ""` before the if statements.

Comment: Like this?? MachineEnd = "StringA" If Combobox.SelectedValue = 5

Comment: Um, my comment is kind of wrong, let me add an answer that will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate the variable outside of the IF construct so it will be in the proper scope. Then use the assignment statement `var = "val"` within the if statements:

```
Dim MachineEnd As String
    'declare machine end string
If Combobox.SelectedValue = 5 Then
    MachineEnd = "StringA"
ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 6 Then
    MachineEnd = "StringB"
ElseIf Combobox.SelectedValue = 7 Then
    MachineEnd = "StringC"
...
    End if
...
```

Comment: See my edited post, comments on this are at the bottom.

Comment: What if you change the declaration to `Dim MachineEnd As String = ""`

Comment: That does not work, however it seems that the problem is coming from my parameter expression underneath my sql statement. If i dont use a parameter and use something like this " & MachineEnd & ", it works. However, leaving code like that makes me worry about an sql injection attack,

Comment: I think I will just set my drop down list so that text can not be entered and since it is bound to an sql datatable I should be safe to use this.

Comment: Could this capital E be causing a problem `"@MachinEFinish"` in addWithValue? Probably not because Microsoft stuff is case-insensitive, right?

Comment: yea, its not that. That was a type-o on my part. My actual code does not show that.